# Regular expression to match cash values in GBP

Tags: node.js, regex

I'm trying to identify strings containing references to cash sums (British pounds), but I need to ignore examples where the monetary value is either:

- immediately preceded by the word "worth" e.g. "worth £200"
- immediately followed by the word "voucher" e.g. "£200 voucher"
- followed by any single word, then the word "voucher" e.g. "£200 shop voucher"

Some examples and the result I would like:

```
Total £500 cash                                <-- Match
£500 cash                                      <-- Match
Thing not worth much, £1 and some shoes        <-- Match
£123 and some shoes                            <-- Match
Total £1,234 and some shoes                    <-- Match
Total £2 and some shoes worth not much         <-- Match
Total £1000000 and some shoes                  <-- Match
A gadget worth £89.99                          <-- NO match
A £50 shop Voucher                             <-- NO match
A £50 shop voucher and something else          <-- NO match
A £50 voucher and something else               <-- NO match
A voucher and £200 cash plus some socks        <-- Match
Total £42 cash, a shop Voucher and some cheese <-- Match
```

The best I have come up with is:

```
^.*(?<!worth )(?<CashValue>£(\d{1,3})(,?\d{1,3})*)(?!( \w* ?voucher)).*$
```

This picks out the cash value correctly, and it excludes the example "worth £89.99" correctly. But I can't get it to exclude on the word "voucher" as I would like.
I'm obviously being a noob and using the lookahead (or lookbehind?) incorrectly or for the wrong thing.

I'm doing this using Node.js.

Answer (score 0):

I arrived at

```
(?<!worth )(?<CashValue>£(\d{1,3})(,?\d{1,3})*) (?!((\b\w*\b )?voucher))
```

which seems to gives expected result : https://regexr.com/3nqu0
I think (one of) the problem with your regex is that  you don't match the spaces correctly in your last group.

Answer (score 0):

In JavaScript, you need to use

```
/(worth\s+)?£(\d[\d.,]*)\b(?!(?:\s+[^\s,]+)*\s*voucher)/i
```

and to check if Group 1 matched. If it does, you should fail the match (if you extract, do not add to the resulting array, if you replace, just put the whole match value back into the resulting string).

**Details**

- `(worth\s+)?` - Group 1: an optional `worth` string and 1+ whitespaces
- `£` - a pound symbol
- `(\d[\d.,]*)` - Group 2: a digit and then 0+ digits, commas or periods
- `\b` - a word boundary
- `(?!(?:\s+[^\s,]+)*\s*voucher)` - there cannot be 0+ sequences of 1+ whitespaces followed with 1+ chars other than whitespace and `,` and then followed with `voucher`

JS demo:

```js
var strs = ["Total £500 cash", "£500 cash", "Thing not worth much, £1 and some shoes", "£123 and some shoes", "Total £1,234 and some shoes", "Total £2 and some shoes worth not much", "Total £1000000 and some shoes", "A gadget worth £89.99", "A £50 shop Voucher", "A £50 shop voucher and something else", "A £50 voucher and something else", "A voucher and £200 cash plus some socks", "Total £42 cash, a shop Voucher and some cheese"];
var rx = /(worth\s+)?£(\d[\d.,]*)\b(?!(?:\s+[^\s,]+)*\s*voucher)/i;
for (var s of strs) {
  var m;
  if (m = s.match(rx)) {
     if (m[1]) {
        console.log(s, "=> No match");
     } else {
        console.log(s, "=>", m[2]);
     }
  } else {
     console.log(s, "=> No match");
  }
}
```

Comment: @DanMcCoy Read my answer again and pay attention to *"check if Group 1 matched. If it does, you should fail the match (if you extract, do not add to the resulting array, if you replace, just put the whole match value back into the resulting string)."* That is why. What you can't achieve with regex, you may get with a bit of code.